# Where is fsck startet for the root filesystem at boot?

Tags: linux, debian, boot, fsck, initramfs

I want to extend an existing **Debian 6.0** system so that it is able to automatically fix a corrupt root file system by restoring a separate image. That process should start automatically instead of the typical

```
UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
```

error message (so that the machine can be left unattended).

I was expecting that some script in `initrd.img` is responsible for checking the root fs (and handling error cases like the one above), but I can't find it. Is that job perhaps done by the Kernel itself or the boot loader (GRUB in this case) ?

(I'm using `initramfs`)

Comment: How about setting it up with a read-only rootfs?

Comment: The problem is that the rootfs needs to be changed from time to time (application upgrades, configurations) and I can't update the initramfs each time. Instead, falling back to a older backup and re-applying the changes is the better way for me.

Comment: Depending on how often you update, it might be viable to do it off-line on the image and just replace it on next boot - e.g. by setting a parameter on kernel command line which the initramfs notices and replaces the rootfs without asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its handled in the init scripts, in particular `/etc/init.d/checkroot.sh`. After this message, you should be dropped into a shell (or given a single user password prompt) to run that fsck.

Its warning you that there is some error in the filesystem beyond the fairly normal (from unexpected power failures, etc.) and trivial to fix errors that `-p` will fix automatically.

You can configure it to do its best to fix everything (at the risk of eating the filesystem, or moving large parts to `lost+found`) by editing `/etc/default/rcS` and setting `FSCKFIX=yes`. (This corresponds to `fsck -y` instead of `fsck -p`)